# Javascript image highlight (explain)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi
I have been designing some websites, using a basic knowledge of javascript and thorough css and html. I have recently been assigned to add some simple drop down menus to another website, this in itself is simple but the website has some existing code which is both long and i dont understand. Simply i would love someone to help me convert this into jQuery and also how it works, ie how can i change it to get it to work with my drop down menus.
Here it is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
    d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
  if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
  for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
  if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}

function MM_nbGroup(event, grpName) { //v6.0
  var i,img,nbArr,args=MM_nbGroup.arguments;
  if (event == "init" && args.length > 2) {
    if ((img = MM_findObj(args[2])) != null && !img.MM_init) {
      img.MM_init = true; img.MM_up = args[3]; img.MM_dn = img.src;
      if ((nbArr = document[grpName]) == null) nbArr = document[grpName] = new Array();
      nbArr[nbArr.length] = img;
      for (i=4; i < args.length-1; i+=2) if ((img = MM_findObj(args[i])) != null) {
        if (!img.MM_up) img.MM_up = img.src;
        img.src = img.MM_dn = args[i+1];
        nbArr[nbArr.length] = img;
    } }
  } else if (event == "over") {
    document.MM_nbOver = nbArr = new Array();
    for (i=1; i < args.length-1; i+=3) if ((img = MM_findObj(args[i])) != null) {
      if (!img.MM_up) img.MM_up = img.src;
      img.src = (img.MM_dn && args[i+2]) ? args[i+2] : ((args[i+1])? args[i+1] : img.MM_up);
      nbArr[nbArr.length] = img;
    }
  } else if (event == "out" ) {
    for (i=0; i < document.MM_nbOver.length; i++) {
      img = document.MM_nbOver[i]; img.src = (img.MM_dn) ? img.MM_dn : img.MM_up; }
  } else if (event == "down") {
    nbArr = document[grpName];
    if (nbArr)
      for (i=0; i < nbArr.length; i++) { img=nbArr[i]; img.src = img.MM_up; img.MM_dn = 0; }
    document[grpName] = nbArr = new Array();
    for (i=2; i < args.length-1; i+=2) if ((img = MM_findObj(args[i])) != null) {
      if (!img.MM_up) img.MM_up = img.src;
      img.src = img.MM_dn = (args[i+1])? args[i+1] : img.MM_up;
      nbArr[nbArr.length] = img;
  } }
}
//-->
</script>
```

Many Thanks

Comment: I think you can use this directly, all the scripts listed up were written by the basic syntax

Comment: @Paul what do you mean by this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like code left over from an old WYSIWYG editor (`MM` may be the acronym of `MacroMedia`).

By the time you de-obfuscated it and figured out what it does, you may as well have rewritten it in a readable way with jQuery.

#### Update

I just looked at [your site](http://www.sundalah.com.au/), and the effect looks like it could be achieved using CSS alone (more specifically, the `:hover` pseudo class).

#### Update

I'd rather use CSS and background images, but this will work if you want to keep `img` elements. Just name the *hover* state image something sane.

Also, why does every `li` have its own `ul` parent... weird.

```
$('#nav li a img').each(function() {
   var originalSrc = this.src,
       hoverSrc = originalSrc.replace(/\.(gif|png|jpe?g)$/, '_hover.$1'); 

   $(this).hover(function() {
      this.src = hoverSrc;
   }, function() {
      this.src = originalSrc;
   });
});
```

Comment: Would love to, but the thing is what this code does is if you check this page http://www.sundalah.com.au. It provides the highlight as you move your mouse of the menu which is constructed using images. Oh and thanks for restructuring my post.

Comment: I use the :hover pseudo class all the time, the problem is that the menu ins't text it is constructed of images and on each of the pages the images are different. I really don't want to make a second "hover" image for every single one of the menu images on all of the pages.

Comment: @Jason `:hover` can change `background-image`.

Comment: @alex how is that useful? I need to change a property of the image without changing the image. I have thought of overlaying text on the image however that gets a little bit over complicated for a simple menu highlight. I just wanted to give a similar affect to what is currently done on the www.sundalah.com.au page

Comment: Look visit http://www.letsmine.info/Sundalah, it is my testing server. Can you suggest what i should do to the menu on that site to give a similar hover affect as the existing site.

Comment: @Jason Sure, but please don't be rude to people trying to help you.

Comment: @Jason Why is every `li` in its own `ul`?

Comment: @alex Sorry if i sounded like i was being rude

Comment: @Jason See update. Also, showing `phpinfo()` on your site will only help people that want to do bad things to your site.

Comment: Is that not how you would structure it? <div><ul><li>Main Item<ul><li>Drop Item</li></ul><li>Next Main Item<ul><li>Drop From That</li></ul></li></ul></div>

Comment: @Jason I didn't know they had drop down items.

Comment: Check out my linked css style sheet may help you understand http://www.letsmine.info/Sundalah/css/drop.css

Comment: when you say hover state what do you mean by that? I have only just started using jquery, so i have just some few basic questions to ask, first what do you mean by hover state and second what does this script actually do like how does it work. I like to understand what i put on my websites.

Comment: @Jason It changes the `img` elements' `src` attribute, by making a filename such as `a.jpg` to `a_hover.jpg`.

Comment: Ok never mind after actually concentrating a little bit harder i understand. Still means however i am going to need to make a second image for every menu item and the menu items vary on every page.

Comment: @alex didn't see your new comment till after i commented.

Comment: @alex Ok i will just make those images and quit complaining Thank You, one last question how do i vote a answer.

Comment: @Jason Push the up arrow on the top left of the answer above the `0`.

Comment: Hehe, never mind at some of my earlier stupid comments, this basically does the same thing as the previous one, i never noticed the hover version of the menu images ... Voting your answer now

Comment: @alex Oh i haven't used my server in ages to i forget it was there

Comment: @alex Only just got to testing your code after renaming all my images and it doesn't work even after changing it from #nav li a img to #nav ul li a img

Comment: @alex Currently the image names are linkname_pagename_hover.jpg is this too long i only added the _hover the rest was how it was before i did anything.

Comment: @Jason You need to wrap the code with `$(function() { ... })`.

Comment: @alex As i mentioned earlier i am not very good with jQuery, what do you mean by wrapping the code?

Comment: @alex I think i understand what you are saying, i will try it.

Comment: @Jason Where the `...` is the code sample I supplied in the answer.

Comment: @alex Have one issue. Your script doesn't preload the images, ruining the hover effect.

Comment: @Jason You can loop through and do that easily enough.

Comment: @alex As I have previously mentioned my javascript knowledge is limited (something i intend on changing), can you provide an update in your answer to explain how to do this.

Comment: @Jason You might be better asking a new question. Stack Overflow isn't really meant to be used in this way (new questions in comments). Feel free to link me to your new question, however.

Comment: @alex Ok i will make a new question, however i felt this linked to my original.

Comment: @Jason Feel free to link back to this question in your new one.

Comment: @alex This is the new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797929/preloading-image-source-in-javascript