# Preloading Image, (source in javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok I previously asked how to do a javascript image hover effect, however the effect doesn't allow the images to be previously preloaded. I was wondering if anyone could help me improve/make new script that will preload the images requested. Here is the code:

```
$('#nav li a img').each(function() {
   var originalSrc = this.src,
       hoverSrc = originalSrc.replace(/\.(gif|png|jpe?g)$/, '_hover.$1'); 

   $(this).hover(function() {
      this.src = hoverSrc;
   }, function() {
      this.src = originalSrc;
   });
});
```

Comment: @alex What do you do to change the formatting anyway?

Comment: There is a *code* display that does syntax highlighting and preserves formatting. The button is in the editor and looks like `{}`. You can also indent the code by 4 spaces.

Comment: @alex Tried that earlier didn't seem to work when i copy pasted my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a generic one...

```
(function() {
    var imgs = ['a.jpg', 'b.jpg'],
        imgsLength = imgs.legnth,
        index = 0,
        loadNextImage = function() {

            var image = new Image();

            image.onload = function() {
                if (index == imgsLength) {
                   return;   
                }
                index++;
                loadNextImage();
            }

            image.src = imgs[index];
        }
}();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/Ffraw/).

...or for your specific example...

```
$('#nav li a img').each(function() {
   var originalSrc = this.src,
       hoverSrc = originalSrc.replace(/\.(gif|png|jpe?g)$/, '_hover.$1'); 
       image = new Image();

   image.src = hoverSrc;

   $(this).hover(function() {
      this.src = hoverSrc;
   }, function() {
      this.src = originalSrc;
   });
});
```

This will load them all when the JavaScript is ran. There is no handler on their `load` event, so you may wish to add one and not display the hover effect until they have in fact been downloaded.

Comment: @alex Will check it isn't my fault but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @alex Just realised i hadn't put it in a function() {} I need that right?

Comment: @Jason Well, which one are you using? The first or second example?

Comment: @alex Second but refer to my previous comment.

Comment: @alex Oh and your reference to the load event. They are only kilobytes big, they should download much much faster then other parts of the page so i don't think it will be a problem. If i did want to add a load even how would I, or should i ask another question?

Comment: @Jason You could probably refer to the first code example to see how that would work. But if you ask a new one, I'll answer it :)

Comment: @alex I get the basics, but i think i will ask another question, doesn't hurt.

Comment: @alex New question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800474/jquery-load-event-with-my-code

Answer (score 1):

Create div and put your rollover/hover images in it then hide the div

```
<div style="display:none">
    <img src="" />
    <img src="" />
    etc..
</div
```

This will load the images without having to use javascript at all, but there is a known problem with Opera using this method.. But I use it all the time works fine.