# jQuery load event with my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok i have some jquery javascript which i intend on adding a .load() event to, hopefully someone can assist me.

```
$(function() {

  $('#nav li a img').each(function() {
   var originalSrc = this.src,
       hoverSrc = originalSrc.replace(/\.(gif|png|jpe?g)$/, '_over.$1'); 
       image = new Image();

   image.src = hoverSrc;

   $(this).hover(function() {
      this.src = hoverSrc;
   }, function() {
      this.src = originalSrc;
   });
  });
})
```

Comment: Have you had a look at the documentation? There are examples: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: Yes, don't worry this is somewhat between alex and me.

Comment: It's not fair to say that because Stack Overflow questions can be commented/answered by anyone. @Felix I have been commenting a bit with @Jason helping him with jQuery and image loading in his previous questions.

Comment: @alex, @Jason: No worries :) Good work @alex!

Comment: @alex i understand i just couldn't think how to explain it which you did perfectly Thank you @alex @felix. @alex i have also made one final question for you which i would love you to help me with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800739/expanding-to-include-current-document-name-in-jquery-script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you set the `src` property of the `Image`, attach the callback like so...

```
image.onload = function() {
  // The image has loaded successfully.
}
```

When the image has loaded and is successful, it will call that function.

If the function is not successful, it will call the function assigned to the `onerror` property.

Alternatively, you can use `$(image).load(function() { ... })`.

Comment: Did you edit my post after i posted it? I actually did it right after i edited it. So where does this go in my/your code.

Comment: is it correct i simply place the previous code inside the { }

Comment: @Jason Place it before you set the `src` property, but *after* you have instantiated `image`. So place it immediately before the `image.src = hoverSrc;` line.

Comment: was just reading about callbacks so i sort of understand now :)