# Expanding to include current document name in jquery script

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have some code which preloads images independent of their extension and acts in a way similar to the :hover pseudo class. My question is how can i expand this to include part of the filename in the source. What i mean is the script currently adds _over to the existing filename and leaves the extension also preloading these images. What i want is for it to add /index_files/filename_imagename_over where the imagename is the src of the image. So it already adds _over i want it to add /index_files/ which is static and /filename which changes based on the file name.

```
$(function() { $('#nav li a img').each(function() {
var originalSrc = this.src,
   hoverSrc = originalSrc.replace(/\.(gif|png|jpe?g)$/, '_over.$1'); 
   image = new Image();

image.src = hoverSrc;

$(this).hover(function() {
  image.onload = function() {
}
  this.src = hoverSrc;
}, function() {
  this.src = originalSrc;
});
});
})
```

I am also wondering if i can include php script in my javascript, i presume i cant because the server wont process the php because it isn't a .php file.
This is the example.
    
If so can i use this in the script.
I suppose it would also be possible to simply use a php include() for the javascript into my php document so that the script is included at the server level and the php code is processed.

Comment: You should be able to get all that going based on the previous answers. Oh, and congrats on figuring out the code format button :)

Comment: @alex Hehe, just realised all lines after that need the spacing to be right as well. Can you directly answer the question because i am going to need to insert the php into a select part of the script.

Comment: @alex Never mind realised i don't need to set it in the document. If i set the documentname_imagename in my php document then when the javascript receives it, it will be correct because the php is calculated server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another easy solution would be to use the images as backgrounds (css) and for the hoover effect you change the background position e.g. http://www.dynamicsitesolutions.com/css/background-image-switching/

Comment: Have seen this but i have already got a nice script going don't really want to recode it when neither is more efficient.

Comment: since i answered my own question, however this answer is still usefull you get my vote